# Culture and LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, linq-to-xml

For serializing basic types, LINQ to XML uses the invariant culture, however if I have a class that looks like this:

```
class C
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return Value.ToString(provider);
    }
}
```

And pass an instance of `C` as content to `XElement`:

```
new XElement("name", new C { Value = 5.1 });
```

The basic `.ToString()` is called instead of `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. This appears to be an anomaly between the behavior for built-in types and for user-defined classes.

Is there any way to get LINQ to XML to use the invariant culture for user-defined classes?

Comment: From looking the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3367036406d1344a) we can see that `(string)content` will be called.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev If I don't define a conversion to string, I don't see how this can work?

Comment: But what's a problem? I see `ToString` is called in `GetStringValue` so if you override it in your class you can use whatever culture you want in it. Do you want to set culture globally to not to have to override `ToString` ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to implement `IXmlSerializable` like so:

```
class C : IXmlSerializable {
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider) {
        return Value.ToString(provider);
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteElementString("Value", Convert.ToString(Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it seems that WriteXml is never called - the object gets serialized exactly as before.